# Rake db:seed rake aborted! ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm a beginning rails student at OneMonth learning stripe payments. Right now, I'm learning how to create a product table and seed the database. Everything's been smooth so far until I encountered a problem after running rake db: seed

**Davids-MBP-2:one_month_stripe_payments DKP$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken**
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in`save!'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in`block in save!'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`block in transaction'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`transaction'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in`with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in`create!'
/Users/DKP/Desktop/one_month/one_month_stripe_payments/db/seeds.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`load'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`load_dependency'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in`load_seed'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in`block (2 levels) in '
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/DKP/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I've tried rake db: reset, then rake:db migrate, then rake db: seed again. But i still have the same error.

Could anyone help me with this problem please? I'm feeling stuck and I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks so much!

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `rake db:reset`, what rails does is `rake db:drop` -> `rake db:create` -> `rake db:migrate` -> `rake db:seed`.

You DO NOT need to `rake db:seed` again.

you can check your console by doing `rails c` and see if you seed data is already inside. `Product.all`

Comment: I'm getting this error now after running rake db:reset. rake db:seed rake aborted! ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'length' for Product. I'm still new to coding, so i don't know how to read this on my own yet. Any thoughts on how to solve this problem? Thanks again!

Comment: @codingnoob You're getting `UnknownAttributeError` because you don't have a column in your Product table. Have you generated the length column yet? If not, you can do `rails generate migration AddLengthToProducts length:integer`. Then do a `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 3):

'Email has already been taken' means you have a record with the same email already present.

Do Rails console and check if the records are there or not.
If not, do rake db:drop -> rake db:create -> rake db:migrate -> rake db:seed. This will solve your problem.

Comment: I couldn't find the email records in rail console, so i followed your suggestion to rake db:drop ... rake db: seed. But when i did rake db: seed, i get this error now:  rake db:seed
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'length' for Product.  I'm still new to coding, so i don't know how to read this. Any thoughts on how to solve this problem? Thanks again!